# C# Append byte array to existing file

Tags: c#, arrays, byte, append, concatenation

I would like to append a byte array to an already existing file `(C:\test.exe)`. Assume the following byte array:

```
byte[] appendMe = new byte[ 1000 ] ;

File.AppendAllBytes(@"C:\test.exe", appendMe); // Something like this - Yes, I know this method does not really exist.
```

I would do this using File.WriteAllBytes, but I am going to be using an ENORMOUS byte array, and System.MemoryOverload exception is constantly being thrown. So, I will most likely have to split the large array up into pieces and append each byte array to the end of the file.

Thank you,

Evan

Comment: I don't understand the problem.

Comment: My main goal is to add two enormous byte arrays together. This is not possible, however, as an exception (out of memory) is thrown. So, my solution is to write each byte array to an output file separately, (as opposed to combining them and writing them to the file as one).

Comment: You should at least provide some code that you've tried... So far it is unclear what is causing your problem - all Stream and Writer classes are able to write byte arrays directly.

Comment: What is so difficult to understand about "append a byte array to an already existing file" ? Everyone else seemed to understand it...

Answer (score 91, accepted):

One way would be to create a [`FileStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx) with the [`FileMode.Append`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode.aspx) creation mode.

> Opens the file if it exists and seeks to the end of the file, or
>   creates a new file.

This would look something like:

```
public static void AppendAllBytes(string path, byte[] bytes)
{
    //argument-checking here.

    using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append))
    {
        stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks perfect. Some other answers use BinaryWriter; why would one choose this over the FileStream method?  I'm guessing it performs exactly the same function, but takes more lines of code.

Comment: does it need to flush?

Comment: @JohnDemetriou after you get out of the block from the using statement, Close() gets called, which will in turn will call Flush(); so I don't think you need to call Flush()

Answer (score 7):

1. Create a new `FileStream`.
2. `Seek()` to the end.
3. `Write()` the bytes.
4. `Close()` the stream.

Comment: This seems to be the best solution to my problem. I'll give it a go and let you know. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can also use the built-in `FileSystem.WriteAllBytes Method (String, Byte[], Boolean)`.

```
public static void WriteAllBytes(
    string file,
    byte[] data,
    bool append
)
```

Set append to **True** to append to the file contents; **False** to overwrite the file contents. Default is False.

Comment: As far as I can tell this is a VB.Net only solution. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.writeallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3):

I'm not exactly sure what the question is, but C# has a `BinaryWriter` method that takes an array of bytes.

[BinaryWriter(Byte[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bx149a0k.aspx)

```
bool writeFinished = false;
string fileName = "C:\\test.exe";
FileStream fs = new FileString(fileName);
BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
int pos = fs.Length;
while(!writeFinished)
{
   byte[] data = GetData();
   bw.Write(data, pos, data.Length);
   pos += data.Length;
}
```

Where `writeFinished` is true when all the data has been appended, and `GetData()` returns an array of data to be appended.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply create a function to do this

```
public static void AppendToFile(string fileToWrite, byte[] DT)
{
    using (FileStream FS = new FileStream(fileToWrite, File.Exists(fileToWrite) ? FileMode.Append : FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write)) {
        FS.Write(DT, 0, DT.Length);
        FS.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: using{} does not need calling `FS.Close();`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach using MemoryStream:

```
public static byte[] GetLargeBytes(byte[] bytes)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(new byte[1024 * 1024 * 10], true))
    {
        stream.Write(bytes);
        stream.Position = 0;
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}
```